# Four-fermion "contact" interactions differing from those arising from the Standard Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement

In the 1998 article [Compositeness Test at the FMC with Bhabha Scattering](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25229253.pdf), it states that:

> It was pointed out that the existence of quark and lepton substructure will be
>   signalled at energies well below Λ by the appearance of four-fermion “contact”
>   interactions which differ from those arising in the standard model [3,4]. These
>   interactions are induced by the exchange of bound states associated with the new
>   gauge interactions.

What are the four-fermion contact interactions according to the Standard Model?  How do they differ in actual experiments, if they do?  What are the bound states associated with the new gauge interactions?

Comment: They are dimension-6 operators of the form $\mathcal{L} \subset \frac1{M^2} \bar\psi \psi \bar\psi \psi$.

Comment: In the SM they correspond to Fermi four fermions interaction describing the weak force.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction particularly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction .